# Unable to deploy using fabric8:deploy maven plug-in

Tags: maven, jbossfuse

I'm trying to deploy a simple Camel route to my local instanct of JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 server.

I'm trying to use fabric8:deploy maven plug-in.

I created fabric using fabrc:create.

In settings.xml, added fabric server.

```
<server>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
  <id>fabric8.upload.repo</id>
</server>
```

In pom.xml, added fabric8:deploy maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.redhat-621084</version>
    <configuration>
        <profile>sampleprofile</profile>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Then, I run

mvn fabric8:deploy -Dfabric8.jolokiaUrl=http://localhost:8181/jolokia -DskipTests -X

I'm getting below error.

Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8181 failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:133)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:54)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.jolokia.client.J4pClient.execute(J4pClient.java:190)
        ... 25 more

Any idea where is the problem? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure Fuse is running on localhost and port is correct? What do you see in browser for [http://localhost:8181/jolokia]? You should see authentication request and then some json string. Also try to use latest version of the plugin